# Updated versions of Chrome not validating local Certificate Authority and Certificate

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

We're running on Windows server.  Our setup includes installing a root and intermediate CA in windows through the Certificate snap in on MMC.  This used to work fine, and we had no problems loading our website through Chrome with the connection recognized as secure.  However, recently Chrome has moved to use its own Certificate store.  Initially we were able to set ChromeRootStoreEnabled to false in the registry which allowed our Certificates to still be recognized as secure.  But it seems a recent update from Chrome disabled that setting in the registry so now our site is not recognized as secure.

This is all running on an offline network.  Along with the new root store I believe that chrome has a new certificate validator.  From some things I've read online, it sounds like Chrome should still recognize local Certificate Authorities installed on a system.  Is that true? We are trying to nail down if our issue stems from Chrome not recognizing the certificate authority on the system or if instead it is having issues verifying the certificate with its new verification method.  Any ideas how to add support back for our Certificate and Certificate Authorities?